# Filter geoserver layers based on postgis geometry

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geometry, filter

I am wondering how, and if it is possible, to filter a geoserver's layer (from a large shapefile) on a specific geometry coming from a postgis table.

I have a huge shapefile for a country. I'd like the user to only be able to view a limited area of the layer he has been granted permission for (a city or whatever). The geometry he is allowed to see is stored as a multipolygon in a postgis table.

Is there a way to do that directly in geoserver (**server-side**)?

If not, could you give me some hints / technologies to use?

Comment: filtering is possible both with wfs and wms filtering. wfs should be more straight forward

Comment: @elasticrash this is done on the client side ? I would prefer a solution on the geoserver server

Comment: you could filter a layer directly through SLD but you need something like an Id or an attribute and that can't come from anywhere else really than either being hard-coded or from the client. What are you trying to achieve. cause geoserver layers cannot "talk" to other tables. except if you create a  geoserver extension https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/src/extension

Comment: Look for the cross layer filter plugin

Answer (score 1):

As you want to use Postgis, what about this (tested) workaround:

1. migrate your large SHP to your Postgis;
2. Create a Geoserver SQL View Layer with the SQL filter logic, using, for example, `ST_Intersects`;
3. This layer also use "*SQL view parameters*" to pass the ID (or name, or whatever field you want) so you can pass the value with "`viewparams`" parameter.

Check this [page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html#parameterizing-sql-views) from Geoserver doc.